# List indices must be integers error

Tags: python

I have the following error coming in my Python code:

```
if data['result'] == 0:
TypeError: list indices must be integers, not str
```

Following is the code :

```
data = urllib.urlencode(parameters)
req = urllib2.Request(url, data)
try:
    response = urllib2.urlopen(req)
except urllib2.URLError, e:
    self.redirect('/error')
json_post = response.read()
data = json.loads(json_post)
response_dict = simplejson.loads(json_post)

virustotal = VirusTotal()
if data['result'] == 0:
    virustotal_result = True

elif data['result'] == -2:
    self.response.out.write("API Request Rate Limit Exceeded<br/>")
elif data['result'] == -1:
    self.response.out.write("API Key provided is wrong<br/>")
elif data['result'] == 1:
    self.response.out.write("Time Stamp : %s<br/>"% data['report'][0])
```

I know that data is a list. So I changed it into integers as well but the code then showed the range error. Please Help??

Comment: What do you get if you print `data`?

Answer (score 1):

When you say `data = json.loads(json_post)`, it sounds like you got a list, not the dict you seem to be expecting.

If this isn't the problem, try updating with the full traceback and the value of `json_post`.

Comment: I am new to python and I read about dicts and lists but I don't know how to change it into integers' indices now.

Comment: The answer depends on understanding the data that you have. Consider reading http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/ to learn about Python datatypes.

Answer (score 1):

You are getting an array of objects back from `response.read`, which means you're getting a Python `list`. Try this:

```
 data = json.loads(json_post)[0]
```